# Athena Query taking very long

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a large Textfile file which is pipe delimited with probably over million records. I am copying it into s3 and then loading it into athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main
                      ( `pin` string,
                        `service_location_no` string,
                        `practice_type` string)
                      ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
                      WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
                        'serialization.format' = '|',
                        'field.delim' = '|',
                        'collection.delim' = 'undefined',
                        'mapkey.delim' = 'undefined'
                      ) LOCATION 's3://file_bucket/ci/main_file/main/'
                      TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I have another smaller file (same format ) and load it into athena

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS static
                         ( `pin` string,
                            `service_location_no` string,
                            `practice_type` string)
                      ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
                      WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
                        'serialization.format' = '|',
                        'field.delim' = '|',
                        'collection.delim' = 'undefined',
                        'mapkey.delim' = 'undefined'
                      ) LOCATION 's3://file_bucket/ci/static_file/static/'
                      TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

So i now have 2 tables main and static. Both have same columns.
My goal is to create a 3 rd table which contains records from main and static with below query.

```
   CREATE TABLE final
                        WITH (
                          format = 'TEXTFILE',
                          external_location = 's3://file_bucket/ci/final_file/final/',
                          field_delimiter = '|',
                          bucketed_by = ARRAY['pin'],
                          bucket_count = 1
                        ) AS
                        SELECT   *
                FROM     main m
                WHERE   pin NOT IN (SELECT  DISTINCT pin FROM static)
                UNION
                SELECT  * FROM static
```

This is taking over 2 hours and it times out. I am trying to see if it can be accomplished in a more efficient way.

Comment: `NOT IN` is notoriously inefficient. It effectively needs to look through every row to determine whether to NOT include something. You might be able to improve performance by first making a table of distinct 'pins', then perform an OUTER JOIN to that table and retrieve rows where there is a NULL joined table. (Sorry, that description isn't very elegant.) Basically, it finds rows that do not JOIN, rather than finding rows that are 'not in' a large list.

Comment: John, compute-wise, `NOT IN` and `OUTER JOIN` + filter on NULL is the more or less the same problem. OUTER JOIN can lead to cardinality explosion though.
First thing would be to remove DISTINCT from `NOT IN` subquery.
Presto does that automatically, but not the old version which Athena is based on.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems: the `NOT IN` check against a `DISTINCT` query is probably slow, as others have pointed out in comments, but another, potentially more significant issue is your partitioning. How many distinct values are there in `main` for the `pin` column? The name suggests it's not a low cardinality column, but I may of course be wrong. It might be that there's too many distinct values to write output for.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the query a bit below and it helped. I also had to increase the  time out for DML Query to 3 hrs as it took ~ 2.5 hrs

```
SELECT              m.*
FROM                main m
LEFT OUTER JOIN     static s
   ON               m.pin = s.pin
WHERE               s.pin is null  
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM static
```

There are total of around 1 million records in main.
pin is not unique - there can be 1 row with a unique pin or 1000 rows with same pin

I was wondering if i can get partitioning done on the main or static table by pin but from what i understand , the files in S3 have to be partitioned by pin
However, I get 1 giant file and has all the pins. I was wondering if anything can be done in terms of partitioning the table here, if possible at all?